# Tell the ConTeXt index which occurrence is the defining one

Tags: context, indexing

I have a document which defines quite some terms. I want to create an index where those terms are listed, along with prominent usages. In the index, I want to differentiate between the page that defines the link and occurrences. I also want the terms be clickable and link to the defining occurrence with `coupling=yes`. So, if a term is defined on page 3 and is referenced on page 1 and 5, it should look something like this:

> term   1, **3**, 5

and link to the occurrence on page 3.

As I understand the documentation, coupling will setup my index to link to the first or last occurrence, which is not helpful in this case. I also understand that there are processors, but they are used for styling the entry, not the page numbers.

Is this possible to do with ConTeXt registers?

Comment: “I want *list of things*” is not a question.

Comment: The two things I want – having one page number bold and linking to that occurrence – are tightly coupled. I don't think it makes sense to split them into two questions.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert, but there is a comment on the [Wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupregister) for `setupregister` under `coupling` that states "(no effect in MkIV?)". This might not say much, but I couldn't get it to work myself...

As for the styling, I do think it's possible to get what you want with processors:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\defineregister[index][pagestyle=normal,n=2]
\defineprocessor[definition][style=italic,color=blue]

\starttext

    \placeindex \page[yes]

    First occurrence of term\index{term}\index{term}. \page[yes]
    Second occurrence of term where it is defined\index[definition->]{term}. \page[yes]
    Third occurrence of term\index{term}.


\stoptext
```

Which gives:

[image]

In this case, all the numbers are clickable and take you to the right occurrence.